# ¿cual puede ser el problema si no se aplican los identificadores(identifying) en la bases de datos o si se aplican de manera herrones?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Buenos días el motivo de mi preguntas sobre **`identifying` y `non-identifying relationship`** estado averiguando sobre el temas el concepto creo que ya lo entendí, pero tengo una duda sobre que pasaría si al momento de realizar el moldeamiento de mi base de datos(**modelo e-r**) no se tiene en cuenta el identificador en la relaciones entre las entidades. Ejemplos: si se tiene una base de datos  y solo se realizar el moldeamiento de la base de datos y solo se hace con `non-identifying relationship` pero en la base de datos  hay campos que si tiene relación identificadores , por no aplicar de manera adecuada  ya sea el  **`identifying` o `non-identifying relationship`**  solo aplicando uno de los 2 en la base de datos eso en que afecta en la base de datos .

[image: un ejemplo utilizando solo non identifying relationship]

Comment: No se entiende mucho el problema.. es un problema conceptual?

Comment: @gbianchi si  es que no entiendo que pasa si un hace el E-R  ignorando el identifying  eso puede  generar problemas  al momento de implementar la base de datos

Comment: @gbianchi entiendo que cuando uno hace E-R  se hace teniendo en cuenta  el  identifying o non-identifying relationship dependiendo  de la base de datos mi pregunta es que pasa si uno al momento de hacer el modelo entidad relacion  lo hace como caiga eso afecta a la base de datos y en que lo afecta

Comment: En realidad, no pasa nada, pero depende de tu profesor. Las relaciones son teoricas, y en la practica no se usan (o si, depende quien te conteste). Entonces no sabria como responderte...